# Filtered colimits in type theory

Tags: type-theory

My question is, what is a type theoretic way of expressing filtered colimits?

Suppose, for instance, that we would like to express the filtered colimit of objects in a dependent type theory. How might one do this?

Comment: Are you talking about filtered colimits of types? It's impossible to do this in plain MLTT, we need quotient types to define them. If we add those, then any colimit of types can be defined like in set theory as a quotient of the sum of types in the diagram.